# How to alter table and update column values in the same area / stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, alter-table

Sorry for the poor title, I'm just not sure how to explain the issue in a single sentence.

I have this bit of code in a stored procedure:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.raw_customer', 'LegalName') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [raw_customer] 
        ADD [LegalName] varchar(255)

    UPDATE [raw_customer] 
    SET [LegalName] = [Name]
END
```

When it runs, I get the following error:

> Invalid column name 'LegalName'

and the table is not updated.

I tried splitting into two separate commands:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.raw_customer', 'LegalName') IS NULL
    ALTER TABLE [raw_customer] 
        ADD [LegalName] varchar(255)
        
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.raw_customer', 'LegalName') IS NULL
    UPDATE [raw_customer] 
    SET [LegalName] = [Name]
```

I get the same error.

If I do them manually separately they work, but I can't seem to get them to work together in the stored procedure. The best I can think is that the `ALTER TABLE` needs to be committed before the `UPDATE` can run, but not clear on how to do that. I can't put a `GO` in the middle of the stored procedure.

Comment: You just simply can't do this in a single procedure - SQL Server will look at the *whole* statements and checks them - and thus throws that error. It's generally considered a very bad practice to mix DDL (data definition language - like `ALTER TABLE`) and DML (data manipulation language - like `UPDATE`) statements in the same SQL. You'll need to have two separate procedure - one to actually *alter* the table - and a separate one to do the update

Comment: You can't do it that way, you are getting a *compile time* error, for the `update` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you are trying to do you need to defer the compilation of the `update` statement.

You can do this using `exec sp_executesql`, try the following:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.raw_customer', 'LegalName') IS NULL
BEGIN
   exec sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE [raw_customer] ADD [LegalName] varchar(255)'

   exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [raw_customer] SET [LegalName] = [Name]'
END
```

Comment: Works great, as I read the comments above I wondered if the sp_executesql would work.  Just gave it a try and it worked great.